# virtualenv on macOS uses nonexistent python interpreter

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, homebrew

When I run `virtualenv`, I get this:

```
$ virtualenv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`virtualenv` only started behaving this way today. It worked yesterday. It breaks because `virtualenv` is a Python script using a nonexistent Python interpreter:

```
$ head -1 $(which virtualenv)
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

On my machine, `/usr/local/opt/python` is a symlink to a Python 3.6 directory:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/opt/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jim  admin  24  2 Mar 13:45 /usr/local/opt/python -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.4_3
```

As expected, the Python 3.6 directory does not contain a `bin/python2.7`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/bin/
2to3            idle            pip3            pydoc3.6        python3-config      python3.6m-config   wheel3
2to3-3.6        idle3           pip3.6          python          python3.6       pyvenv
easy_install        idle3.6         pydoc           python-config       python3.6-config    pyvenv-3.6
easy_install-3.6    pip         pydoc3          python3         python3.6m      wheel
```

`virtualenv` clearly expects `/usr/local/opt/python` to contain Python 2 material, but it only contains Python 3 material.

My `/usr/local/opt/python` is managed by Homebrew. I don't know the provenance of my `virtualenv`. How do I find out where my `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` came from?

Which is to blame? My `virtualenv` or Homebrew?

Answer (score 8):

The blame for this lies with `pip`, not Homebrew. My `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` came from `pip install virtualenv`, which embeds an absolute link to the Python interpreter at installation time! I have opened [an issue about this unidiomatic behavior](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5048).

Comment: I rewrote the hash-bang in `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` to point to the aliased python at `/usr/local/bin/python2`.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on my Mac. Maybe it got broken when I updated to Mojave? Who knows.

Resolved with a `brew` install of Python 2:

```
brew install python2
```

This now takes over from my factory-installed Python 2.7 and gives me a new `virtualenv` that works:

```
$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for adding a separate comment here -- I lack the reputation to add a comment to @jameshfisher's answer.

I used homebrew to update python2 on macos to the latest version:

```
~ ❯❯❯ python2 --version
Python 2.7.15
```

Which creates/updates the `python2` symlink in `/usr/local/bin` to link to that particular brew installed update:

```
~ ❯❯❯ ls -ahl =python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 michael  admin    39B  3 Jul 17:11 /usr/local/bin/python2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/bin/python2
```

The shebang in my `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` was:

```
~ ❯❯❯ head -1 $(which virtualenv)
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

Which did not exist:

```
~ ❯❯❯ ls -l /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
ls: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

So modifying the shebang to `#!/usr/local/bin/python2` to use the brew installed updated python2 version was the most appropriate way to go:

```
~ ❯❯❯ virtualenv --version
15.1.0
```

✨✨

A bit of a red herring for me was that I had mistakenly assumed typing `which python` would give me the path to my version of **python2**:

```
~ ❯❯❯ which python
/Users/michael/.pyenv/shims/python
~ ❯❯❯ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2
~ ❯❯❯ which python3
/Users/michael/.pyenv/shims/python3

~ ❯❯❯ /Users/michael/.pyenv/shims/python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

I had forgotten that I had set `pyenv global` to python `3.7.0`. Please don't fall into that trap as I did! ✨✨

Comment: Thanks @jameshfisher for also raising the pip issue -- that discussion really helped me a lot too!